# Properly export/import parts of a JS project

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, package.json

I'm building an npm package (ES6 + Babel) for the first time and I'm having trouble connecting it all together so it can be imported by the end user.

My build (output) folder structure is the same as src:

```
build
    - index.js
    - BaseClass.js
    sublclasses
        - SubClassA.js
        - SubClassB.js
```

`SubClassA` and `SubClassB` import and extend `BaseClass` and are both exported using the `module.exports`. The entry point, `index.js`, has only two lines:

```
import SubClassA from './subclasses/SubClassA'
import SubClassB from './subclasses/SubClassB'
```

`package.json` has the `main` field set to `./build/index.js`.

When installing the project (or npm linking) into a test project, I write:

```
import SubClassA, SubClassB from 'my-package'
```

Import works, but imported classes are undefined. I've tried a couple more ways to do it, but it didn't work.

How should I do it properly?

EDIT: after changing `index.js` to:

```
import SubClassA from './subclasses/SubClassA'
import SubClassB from './subclasses/SubClassB'

module.exports = SubClassA
module.exports = SubClassB
```

it kind of works. 'Kind of' means that if I import both classes in the test project like so:

```
import SubClassA, SubClassB from 'my-package'
```

and then do:

```
let sca = new SubClassA()
```

it turns out to be `SubClassB`. If I ommit `SubClassB` from import, it works normally.

EDIT 2 - SOLUTION:

Per instructions in the comments below, I've changed the `index.js` file like so:

```
export { default as SubClassA } from './subclasses/SubClassA'
export { default as SubClassB } from './subclasses/SubClassB'
```

and I imported it in the test project like so:

```
import { SubClassA, SubClassB } from 'my-project' and it worked.
```

Comment: are you exporting SubClassA and B from main file?

Comment: @maioman you're right, it's not enough to just import them in the main file, like I did. exported them, rebuilt and it worked, but with a new twist this time. I will update my anwer in a minute.

Comment: you should then use it with `import {SubClassA, SubClassB} from 'my-package'`

Comment: yup, works! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not exporting anything from your main file,
using es6 import/export syntax you can directly export it with:

```
export {default as SubclassA} from './subclasses/SubClassA'
export {default as SubclassB} from './subclasses/SubClassB'
```

then to you can use the named imports :

```
{SubClassA, SubClassB} from 'my-package'
```

Comment: I'm also writing a Readme (usage instructions). When exported like this, can it still be imported with the require('...') syntax?

Comment: require/module.exports are originally used for modules so that wouldn't be possible inside a node environment